# Can systemd socket activation restart a service after it has gone dormant?

Tags: systemd

We have a socket service set up to work over UNIX domain sockets (AF_UNIX). We are using systemd's socket activation in order to create the socket and manage the service. What I would like to do is that if the service is idle for a period, it would shut down and systemd would re-activate the service on the next connection. Is this possible with systemd? I DO NOT want to implement inetd style single-socket-per-request handling though.

Comment: That is the whole point!

Comment: I have exactly the same question. Can the socket be "reset" to its initial state on service shutdown (aka waiting for connection to fire the service) ?